# Add values from MySQL result together from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm not sure if I'm overthinking this and being stupid but I'm trying to add all the values from my MySQL result.

Here is my code to fetch the values and store them in an array:

```
$query = "SELECT value FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
$array = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $array[] = $row;
   }
}
      
print_r($array);
```

Now I just need to figure out how I can add these values together and use this array for other things like working out the average. If there is an easier way to do this than storing the results in an array then please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: _"...add these together..."_ - what is "these"? Most likely all of your desired operations can be done in the query itself, but there isn't enough information in your question to make any suggestions.

Comment: you can also use PDO it has possibility to return an ready to use array from SQL, shame for myself, but have no idea if it's possible with mysqli.

Comment: Managed to sort it with the below code.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out myself, I used the below code:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(column) AS value_sum FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

I guess I was overthinking it.